# Broken binary converter. Index error

Tags: python

i have no idea why this is broken. Also dont tell me to use python's built in function because this is designed for some practice not to actually be used. It is binary to decimal that is broken. It has a index error with the variable 'index'

```
    print('Please choose from the list below:')
    print('')
    print('1) Convert from decimal/denary to binary; ')
    print('2) Covert from binary to denary/decimal; ') #Main Menu
    print('3) Infomation and settings (coming soon);')
    print('4) Exit. ')
    print('')
    menu_choice = str(input('Enter your choice here: ')) #User inputs choice here

    if menu_choice == '1':
        dec_binary()
    elif menu_choice == '2':
        binary_dec()
    elif menu_choice == '3':
        print('By Callum Suttle')
    else:
        return 'Thank You'

def dec_binary():                                                          #Module 1: decimal to binary
    dec = int(input('Enter a number in decimal up to 255: '))              #Checks The number is an ok size, could be made bigger         
    while dec > 255:
        dec = int(input('Enter a number up to 255, no more: '))

    power = int(7)     #change 7 to make bigger by 1 digit                                                     
    convert = []

    while power > -1:      #until power goes below zero
        if dec - pow(2, power) >= 0:  #if entered number subtract 2 to the power of var-pow returns posotive number
            convert.append(1)
            power -=1                 # add a 1
            dec = dec - pow(2, power) >= 0
        else:
            convert.append(0)#if not add a zero
            power -=1
    print('')
    print(convert) # print completed number
    print('')
    binary_decimal_converter() #back to main menu

def binary_dec():
    anwser = 0
    l_bi = str(input('Enter a number in binary up to 7 digits: '))
    while len(l_bi) != 7:    #checks for correct length
        l_bi = str(input('Enter a number in binary up to 7 digits, you may add zeros before: '))
    power = 7       #size can be increased by using this
    index = 0
    while index > 6:  #until every power has been checked (in reverse order)
        if l_bi[index] == '1':  #if the digit is equal to 1 
            anwser += pow(2, power)  #add that amount
            power -= 1 #take the power to check next                                          #why is this broken
            index += 1 # add another index to check previous 
        else:
            power -= 1 #as above
            index += 1   #/\
    print('')
    print(anwser) #prints result
    print('')
    binary_decimal_converter() #main menu
```

Comment: Not entirely related to your question, but there's poor design here. The code at the top is a function called binary_decimal_converter() (and I assume you missed the def line when you pasted). What's wrong is that you're trying to effectively do a GOTO back to there by calling it after each conversion, but since it's actually a function call, not a GOTO, you're recursively piling up function calls. You should instead put your menu in a while loop whose condition becomes false when the Exit option is chosen.

Comment: You should separate your code in a way that you have functions that *only* do the conversion (without in- or output), and then have some interface functions which handle the actual user interaction and just call the conversion functions. That way, you can test your conversion functions separately without having to go through all the interaction logic all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some fixes:

```
def binary_dec():
    anwser = 0 
    l_bi = str(input('Enter a number in binary up to 7 digits: '))
    while len(l_bi) > 7:   # LOOP UNTIL LENGTH IS LESS THAN 7 
        l_bi = str(input('Enter... : '))
    power = len(l_bi) - 1  # directly set the power based on length
    index = 0 
    while index < len(l_bi): # CORRECT LOOP CONDITION
```

Comment: Thank you, much closer to my original code and the other option and works great

Answer (score 1):

this doesn't seem right

```
index = 0
while index > 6:  #until every power has been checked (in reverse order)
    ...
```

you never enter this loop, do you?

a better loop would be something like

```
for i, bit in enumerate(l_bi):
   answer += int(bit) * pow(2, 7-i)
```

also, since you're just practicing, you should find a better way to jump from menu to functions and back. you're doing recursive calls, which is a waste of stack, i.e. your functions actually never finish but just call more and more functions.